# Mock a method with parameters

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I'm injecting a dependency `CheckCompatibRepository`. I'm mocking a method `IsCompatible` which has a list as 3rd parameter.

```
 var mockRepositoryCheckCompatib = new Mock<ICheckCompatibilityActDoer>();
            mockRepositoryCheckCompatib.Setup(c => c.IsCompatible(doer, activity, listActivitiesPreDispatched)).Returns(true);
```

The problem is the list. It's populated by the class I'm testing. Honnestly, I don't care about that parameter, I want to mock `IsCompatible` ignoring that parameter. Is that possible?

Otherwise, the mocking just won't catch the method calls. To ease things, I tried by sending the list as an injected dependency in my class. It works until the list starts being populated, then the mock stops catching the calls.

How would you mock this?

Comment: Isn't it `It.IsAny` etc? Isn't this covered in the documentation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), you're looking for the `It.IsAny<T>` method. Since you're changing the values of the list, passing it an object instance is not the right way to go as you would have to continually setup the Mock to handle the new parameter.

The following example will allow the mock to accept any parameter value of type `List<T>`. For the sake of this example, we will use `List<int>`.

```
 var mockRepositoryCheckCompatib = new Mock<ICheckCompatibilityActDoer>();
 mockRepositoryCheckCompatib.Setup(c => c.IsCompatible(doer, activity, It.IsAny<List<int>>())).Returns(true);
```

Edit: I didn't see bzlm's comment from earlier, which essentially answers the question. Please accept his answer if he posts one, I didn't mean to poach it.

Comment: My comment was just that: a quick drive-by note to, at best, point the OP and future answerers in the right direction, without even knowing whether I was correct. Posting an answer on SO could never be considered poaching. Even two nearly-identical answers is perfectly fine - the community will vote on which is better anyway. So you did exactly the right thing. :)